# VHDL 4-bit binary divider

Tags: binary, vhdl, divider

I am trying to make a binary divider to be part of a calculator using VHDL, I have written the code that I think should work but have been stuck for hours, can someone please help me.

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


    entity Div is
    Port ( Ain   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       Bin   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       Q   : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       R   : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
    end Div;

architecture Behavioral of Div is
Signal Atemp : Std_Logic_Vector (3 downto 0);
begin


Proc1: Process (Ain,Bin, Atemp)
variable cnt : STD_LOGIC_Vector(3 downto 0);
begin


if (Ain < Bin) then
        cnt := "0000";
        Atemp <= Ain;
elsif (Ain = Bin) then
        cnt := "0001";
elsif (Ain > Bin) then
        cnt := "0001";
        Atemp <= (Ain - Bin);
        while (Atemp >= Bin) loop
            if(Atemp >=Bin) then
                Atemp <= (Atemp - Bin);
                cnt := cnt + "0001";
            end if;
        end loop;
end if;
Q <= cnt;
R <= Atemp;
end process Proc1;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: What are you stuck on?  Do you have compile errors?  Are you simulating your design?  We need more detail from you on what your specific problem is.

Comment: @peter i get warnings WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <2>(<3><div>). This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process. and WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 4-bit latch for signal <cnt> (and Atemp). Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.

Answer (score 3):

In the iteration part of the divide process, when `Ain > Bin`, the assign
`Atemp <= (Ain - Bin)` is always performed, even if the iteration should be
completed.  Process that assign to a signal also in the sensitivity list, is
hard to get right.

The code may be updated with Atemp as a variable instead, some other
simplifications with removal of unrequired code, and adding value for remainder
when `Ain = Bin`, resulting in architecture as:

```
architecture Behavioral of Div is
begin

  Proc1 : process (Ain, Bin) is
    variable cnt   : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    variable Atemp : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  begin
    if (Ain < Bin) then
      cnt   := "0000";
      Atemp := Ain;
    elsif (Ain = Bin) then
      cnt := "0001";
      Atemp := (others => '0');  -- Added to give correct remainder
    elsif (Ain > Bin) then
      cnt   := "0001";
      Atemp := (Ain - Bin);
      while (Atemp >= Bin) loop
        -- Removed trivial true if statement, since condition identical to condition in while
        Atemp := (Atemp - Bin);
        cnt   := cnt + "0001";
      end loop;
    end if;
    Q <= cnt;
    R <= Atemp;
  end process Proc1;

end Behavioral;
```

The inner process statements may actually be reduced to:

```
cnt   := "0000";
Atemp := Ain;
while (Atemp >= Bin) loop
  Atemp := (Atemp - Bin);
  cnt   := cnt + "0001";
end loop;
Q <= cnt;
R <= Atemp;
```

Whether this will synthesize to the required frequency with the unrolled
`while` is another question, that depends on the target frequency and
technology.

An alternative solution, given the short `Ain` and `Bin`, is to implement the
divider using a constant lookup table, with address as `Ain & Bin` and output
of `Q & R`.  This will evaluate in fixed time, and synthesis is very likely to
reduce considerably if made as combinatorial logic.

Last comment is that you may also want to handle division by zero, when `Bin`
is zero.

Comment: Thank you @MortenZdk, this worked fine, all I had to do is add AND (cnt < "1111") to the while loop so the compiler would accept that it was not infinite.

Comment: @user3034001, if that solution worked for you, please click the Check Mark next to the answer so the question is marked as Answered.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent mistakes, it is advisable to use explicitly the type unsigned or signed when implementing arithmetic circuits. The numeric_std package contains the following arithmetic operators for these types: +, -, *, /, abs, rem, mod.

Below is a suggested code (for unsigned division). Note that some lines in the arch can be eliminated, but were used to make the code more "didactic".

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity divider is
  generic (size: natural := 4);
  port ( 
    A: in std_logic_vector(size-1 downto 0);
    B: in std_logic_vector(size-1 downto 0);
    Q: out std_logic_vector(size-1 downto 0);
    R: out std_logic_vector(size-1 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture direct of divider is 
  signal Auns, Buns, Quns, Runs: unsigned(size-1 downto 0);
begin 

  --Convert inputs to unsigned:
  Auns <= unsigned(A);
  Buns <= unsigned(B);

  --Do the division:
  Quns <= Auns/Buns;
  Runs <= Auns rem Buns; --Or: Runs <= Auns - resize(Quns*Buns, size);

  --Covert results to std_logic_vector:
  Q <= std_logic_vector(Quns);
  R <= std_logic_vector(Runs);  

end architecture
```